# Personalização do Menu

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

Quero trocar fonte e cor dos items e também mudar o fundo do menu, mas não consigo fazer isso no Xml do menu. Imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero também fazer com que os subItems de Despesa apareçam logo abaixo de Despesa. Ele abre um novo menu, fazendo o anterior desaparecer(óbvio).

XML do menu:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnDespesas"
        android:title="Despesas"
        app:showAsAction="never">
        <menu>
            //esconder subHab dentro do group
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subHab"
                android:title="Habitação"
                app:showAsAction="never">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subSaud"
                android:title="Saúde"
                app:showAsAction="never">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subDespPess"
                android:title="Despesas Pessoais"
                app:showAsAction="never">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subEdu"
                android:title="Educação"
                app:showAsAction="never">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subLaz"
                android:title="Lazer"
                app:showAsAction="never">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subOutr"
                android:title="Outros"
                app:showAsAction="never">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnDivida"

        android:title="Organizador de Dívidas"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnAClen"
        android:title="Calendário"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnRanking"
        android:title="Ranking"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnAjuda"
        android:title="Ajuda"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>



</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para trocar a fonte adicione a seguinte classe no seu projeto:

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Na classe que contém seu menu use (altere da maneira necessária) os seguintes métodos:

```
    Menu m = nv.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem mi = m.getItem(i);

        SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
        if (subMenu != null && subMenu.size() > 0) {
            for (int j=0; j <subMenu.size();j++) {
                MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
            }
        }
        applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
    }
```

e

```
    private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
        Typeface univia = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/univia.otf");
        SpannableString item = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
        item.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("" , univia), 0 , item.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(item);
    }
```

Por último, não esqueça que é necessário ter a pasta /assets/fonts/ (no mesmo nível de /java e /res) e colocar sua fonte lá.
Boa sorte!